# Angular 8 - How to push one model data to another model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have page in that i have 3 input fields and a grid with a add button to add data to the grid and a save button to save the whole data, here what i want to try is when a user add some data to the grid instead of making an API request it should save the data locally and when user click on the save button the whole data means grid data plus those 3 input field data should save in the database.

**Paraent Model**

```
export class ParentModel<GridModel> {
  parentId: number;
  totalDue: number;
  totalAmount: number;
  totalDiscount: number;
  childModel: GridModel[];

 constructor(init?: Partial<ParentModel<GridModel>>) {
  Object.assign(this, init);
 }
}
```

**Child Model**

```
export class GridModel {
  parentId: number;
  childId: number;

  deliveyAmount: number;
  taxAmount: number;

 constructor(init?: Partial<GridModel>) {
  Object.assign(this, init);
 }
}
```

My **Service** to share the data between the models

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataShareService{
  private parentSubject: BehaviorSubject<ParentModel<GridModel[]>> = new BehaviorSubject<ParentModel<GridModel[]>>(null);
  //Just in case if need to subscribe
  paretnt= this.parentSubject.asObservable();

constructor() { }

setGridData(griData: GridModel[]) {
  this.parentSubject.value.childModel = griData;
}

setParentData(parenData: ParentModel<GridModel[]>) {
  this.parentSubject.next(parenData);
}

get parentData(): ParentModel<GridModel[]> {
  return this.parentSubject.value;
 }
}
```

**Grid ts file**

```
  saveGridData() {
    this.dataShareService.setGridData(this.gridForm.value);
  }
```

**Parent ts file**

```
  saveParentData() {
    this.dataShareService.setParentData(this.parentForm.value);
  }
```

But this not working as expected so, am i doing something wrong or is there any better way to do it

Comment: It would be nice If you could share some html also to see how structure is

Comment: Also what exactly is not working? No data is added when you press Save? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with angular reactive forms. Google ‘dynamic reactive forms’. It’s a built in feature in angular. When clicking on the add button you can add a form group to the form and build it up before you submit it

That might also solve the challenge with the validation errors when you send a lot of data in one submit. Every form field will show its own error. Also a built in angular feature